# Elgg Installation Problems

Tags: elgg

I am running Apache2.2, with PHP5 and mod_rewrite enabled on a VPS running Ubuntu Hardy. And I am trying to install Elgg1.5. I uploaded it to /var/www, and changed the appropriate permissions.

When I hit the url, it brings me to the installation page where I provide the database info. When I submit the page, I get the following error in my access.log

"Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/engine/lib/._access.php:1)" in file /var/www/engine/start.php (line 182)

I don't see any problems within the .htaccess and engine/settings.php file it creates, and no whitespaces before and after the php tag. Since I haven't hand-touched any files, I have no clue whats causing the error. Anyone's played with Elgg1.5 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It was some corrupt file.